Contextual effects on children's literacy versus numeracy skills
I was wondering - do contextual effects (e.g. living in poorer communities, family background) matter more for developing literacy skills at a young age than numeracy? I was thinking that perhaps numeracy skills can be compensated much more with a child's talent and aptitude even despite living in disadvantaged conditions, hence living in disadvantaged conditions may affect children's writing and reading more.
I wonder if there's any research on this? I cannot seem to land on a specific research study. Thanks everyone!

Welcome to ME.SE! It is a really interesting question. Have you done a literature search and what kind of stuff have you found thus far?
